# UIStackView with custom constraints - "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" when changing axis

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, uistackview

I've stumbled upon an issue with `UIStackView`.
It has to do with the case when there are some custom constraints between the UIStackView and its arranged subviews. When changing the stack view's axis and the custom constraints, the error message `[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.` appears in the console.

Here is a code example which you can paste in a new project to observe the issue:

```
import UIKit

public class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var stateToggle = false

    private let viewA: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.accessibilityIdentifier = "viewA"
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }()

    private let viewB: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.accessibilityIdentifier = "viewB"
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        return view
    }()

    private lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [viewA, viewB])
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.accessibilityIdentifier = "stackView"
        return stackView
    }()

    private lazy var viewAOneFourthOfStackViewHightConstraint = viewA.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.25)
    private lazy var viewAOneFourthOfStackViewWidthConstraint = viewA.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.25)

    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.accessibilityIdentifier = "rootView"

        view.addSubview(stackView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        ])

        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.frame = .init(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 44)
        button.setTitle("toggle layout", for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = .white
        button.backgroundColor = .black
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTap), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)

        updateConstraintsBasedOnState()
    }

    @objc func buttonTap() {
        stateToggle.toggle()
        updateConstraintsBasedOnState()
    }

    private func updateConstraintsBasedOnState() {
        switch (stateToggle) {
        case true:
            stackView.axis = .horizontal
            viewAOneFourthOfStackViewHightConstraint.isActive = false
            viewAOneFourthOfStackViewWidthConstraint.isActive = true
        case false:
            stackView.axis = .vertical
            viewAOneFourthOfStackViewWidthConstraint.isActive = false
            viewAOneFourthOfStackViewHightConstraint.isActive = true
        }
    }
}
```

In this example we're making a stack view with two subviews. We want one of them to take up 25% percent of the area - so we have the constraints to achieve this (one for each orientation), but we need to be able to switch them accordingly. When the switch happens (from vertical to horizontal stack in this case), the error message appears:

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000089ca00 stackView.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x6000012b48c0'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.leading   (active, names: stackView:0x7fe269d07b50 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000089c9b0 stackView.trailing == UILayoutGuide:0x6000012b48c0'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.trailing   (active, names: stackView:0x7fe269d07b50 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000089c730 viewA.width == 0.25*stackView.width   (active, names: viewA:0x7fe269e14fd0, stackView:0x7fe269d07b50 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000008ba990 'UISV-canvas-connection' stackView.leading == viewA.leading   (active, names: stackView:0x7fe269d07b50, viewA:0x7fe269e14fd0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000008ba9e0 'UISV-canvas-connection' H:[viewA]-(0)-|   (active, names: stackView:0x7fe269d07b50, viewA:0x7fe269e14fd0, '|':stackView:0x7fe269d07b50 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000008bab20 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' rootView.width == 375   (active, names: rootView:0x7fe269c111a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000089ce60 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-left' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6000012b48c0'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: rootView:0x7fe269c111a0, '|':rootView:0x7fe269c111a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000089cdc0 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-right' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x6000012b48c0'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)   (active, names: rootView:0x7fe269c111a0, '|':rootView:0x7fe269c111a0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000008ba990 'UISV-canvas-connection' stackView.leading == viewA.leading   (active, names: stackView:0x7fe269d07b50, viewA:0x7fe269e14fd0 )>
```

Notice the constraint: `"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000008ba9e0 'UISV-canvas-connection' H:[viewA]-(0)-|   (active, names: stackView:0x7fe269d07b50, viewA:0x7fe269e14fd0, '|':stackView:0x7fe269d07b50 )>"` which says *"viewA's trailing should be same as stack view's trailing"*. This is not a valid constraint for the horizontal axis layout. But it's not a constraint I've added, it's something internal to the stack view (`UISV-canvas-connection`).

It seems to me that because we're activating/deactivating custom constraint and also the stack view does the same internally when switching axis - there's temporarily a conflict and an error.

Potential solutions / workarounds:

- Workaround 1: Make the custom constraints  have `priority = 999`. This is not a good workaround - not only because it's hacky, but also because in some cases it would result in other layout issues (e.g. when viewA has some internal layout requirements that conflict,  such as subviews with required hugging priority).
- Workaround 2: Remove the arranged views before the axis change and re-add them after the axis change. This works but it's also hacky and might be difficult in practice for some complicated cases.
- Workaround 3: Don't use `UIStackView` at all - implement using regular `UIView` as a container and create required constraints as needed.

Any ideas if this should be considered a bug (and reported to Apple) and if there are other (better?) solutions?

For example is there a way to tell AutoLayout - "I'm about to change some constraints and also the axis of a stack view - just wait until I'm done and then continue evaluating layout".

Comment: Fantastically written question with a fully reproducible example, explanation of what you have tried along with thoughts on possible workarounds.  I've been here over seven years and have seen maybe one other question as nicely stated as this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, both you and iOS have constraints that you need to deactivate and activate.  In order to do it correctly and avoid conflicts, both you and iOS need to deactivate your old constraints before you can start to activate your new constraints.

Here's a solution that works.  Tell the `stackView` to `layoutIfNeeded()` after you have deactivated your old constraint.  Then it will get its constraints in order and you can activate your new constraint.

```
private func updateConstraintsBasedOnState() {
    switch (stateToggle) {
    case true:
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        viewAOneFourthOfStackViewHightConstraint.isActive = false
        stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
        viewAOneFourthOfStackViewWidthConstraint.isActive = true
    case false:
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        viewAOneFourthOfStackViewWidthConstraint.isActive = false
        stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
        viewAOneFourthOfStackViewHightConstraint.isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... docs for `.layoutSubviews()`: *You should not call this method directly.* Could replace that with `stackView.setNeedsLayout(); stackView.layoutIfNeeded();` ***or*** give each of the `viewAOneFourth...` constraints a Priority less than `.required // 1000`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @DonMag, I changed it to `layoutIfNeeded()` and it still does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

While **vacawama**'s answer will do the job, two other options...

1 - Give the constraints a Priority less than `.required` to allow auto-layout to temporarily break the constraint without complaint.

Add this in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
viewAOneFourthOfStackViewHightConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
viewAOneFourthOfStackViewWidthConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
```

and leave `updateConstraintsBasedOnState()` as you originally had it, or

2 - Use different priority levels, and swap them instead of deactivating / activating constraints.

Add this in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
viewAOneFourthOfStackViewHightConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
viewAOneFourthOfStackViewWidthConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
viewAOneFourthOfStackViewHightConstraint.isActive = true
viewAOneFourthOfStackViewWidthConstraint.isActive = true
```

and change `updateConstraintsBasedOnState()` to this:

```
private func updateConstraintsBasedOnState() {
    switch (stateToggle) {
    case true:
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        viewAOneFourthOfStackViewHightConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
        viewAOneFourthOfStackViewWidthConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
    case false:
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        viewAOneFourthOfStackViewWidthConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
        viewAOneFourthOfStackViewHightConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
    }
}
```

I don't know if changing priorities is more or less efficient than changing activations? But might be something to consider.